# Unordered list in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a tooltip containing an unodered list using bootstrap v2.3.2. I am currently using the following html as the content of the tooltip:

```
<p align='left'><b>This alert would have fired:</b></p>
<ul align='left'>
  <li align='left'>1 time in the past week</li>
  <li align='left'>8 times in the past two weeks</li>
  <li align='left'>20 times in the past month</li>
</ul>
```

The current output looks like this:

[image: Tooltip Output]

I would like the 3 list items to be bulleted and have the natural indent of an unordered list but for some reason the tooltip does not behave like this. I am relatively new to html and css so please assume very little css and bootstrap knowledge in any explanations. I will create css classes for this once I have it working correctly so please be easy on my bad practices (if I have any) but do point them out.

Comment: It's not an actual list (ie `ul` or `ol`), but you could use `&bull;` before each `li` to act like a list. You could even set each `li` in the list to not wrap. You could also use a popover which supports HTML content. What have you tried to make this work?

Comment: I have an attribute set `data-html="true"` to allow html in the tooltip and all of my html works as expected other than the lack of bullets on the list items. For the time being I have put `&bull;`'s in my html and set the margin on my own to give me the look I was hoping for. I was just trying to avoid "hacking" my way through this and wanted to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tooltips aren't really designed for displaying HTML code within them (unless you use a tooltip plug-in like Tooltipster (http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/). I would think of a more clever way to incoporate what you want displayed onto the page without using a tooltip. I put some code below which is easy to read, that shows the error of trying to use HTML within a tooltip.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p align='left' data-toggle="tooltip" title = "'<br>'One'<br>'Two">This alert would have fired:</p>

 </body>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Edit: Here's a good reference on Bootstrap's tooltips. Nothing wrong with saying you're "new" to web development by the way. We all have to start somewhere :-)
 -> http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp

Comment: I agree that a tooltip probably isn't my best bet for displaying html. However when I use this attribute `data-html="true"` I am able to avoid the situation you're talking about, but I'm sure it's still fragile. The design decision to use a tooltip to display this html content was not my own so I'll be sure to use the "it's really not built for that" argument to use something more correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yea, like I said you can use the plug-in and do it though. I did it before but using that plugin. Also, look at hulu.com and check out their tool-tips, it really can help out with tool-tip design. Also, don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if you agree and are pleased with it :-)

Comment: I will definitely check out the plugin. I'm trying to avoid bringing too many plugins, libraries, etc into this web application because of the approval process I will have to go through, but it may be worth it. Thank you for the help and you have my upvote and accepted answer unless a true css fix for this weird behavior comes along.

Comment: The plugin is very lightweight in nature. I wouldnt worry too much about it (if performance is an issue)